# Problem using docker compose file generated by VS 2019 on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2019

I have some kind of problem running multi container application on Mac.
I have 3 containers working together: 2 simply web api (.NET Core) and the official container RabbitMQ, the 2 api exchange events using RabbitMq service.
The application runs correctly running docker compose project from Visual Studio debug, when Api1 receive a POST it creates some data on DB and send message to Api2 using rabbit; Api2 receive the message sent by Api1, both api are visible on localhost... so far so good.

When I try to move the application from Visual Studio debug to Docker I get some problems, my idea was to use the docker compose file generated by VS on the CLI of docker (docker-compose up), following the sequence of action I've done:

1) Executing **docker-compose up** from Docker CLI, the build of the containers present in docker-compose failed (I was expecting VS just execute the same **docker-compose up** during debug, so I was expecting the same results, but probably I was wrong).
**Solution**: I've removed the build and use the images created by VS during previous debug test (still available in docker image local repository), this bypass the build problem (I have to investigate anyway the reasons, but let's move to next point)

2) After step 1 I can run **docker-compose up** without error, but the 2 containers with the 2 apis exit immediately with code 0, the RabbitMQ container doesn't have any problems and keep running as expected.
**Solution**: I've add **stdin_open:true** and **tty:true** in docker-compose to solve this strange issue

3) After step 2 I've executed **docker-compose up** and I was able to see all containers running correctly, but the 2 api containers are not reachable anymore on localhost (the related port are exposed and published), so I cannot send any POST request to the api anymore

I am not a big expert of Docker, but to run this simple multi container application took me much more time than expected, and still I have doubts and issues, any suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found and fixed all issues, I report here because I suppose should be useful for other people:

1) This issue is related to a bug in VS 2019, the problem occurred when you include in a solution some projects (in my case class library) that are not in the same folder of the solution, this will generate wrong destination path for the COPY command in the dockerfile, for this reason the build fail.
I've reported issue to Microsoft:
[Wrong Copy command in Dockerfile](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1015546/wrong-copy-command-in-dockerfile.html)
meanwhile waiting for a fix you can put all the project used in a solution in the same solution folder, this avoid the wrong path generated in dockerfile and therefore the failure of the build procedure.

2) This issue is present only in images created by docker-compose in debug (normally you can recognize them by the tag "dev"), these image are useful for debug but do not use them outside VS debug.
Once fixed point 1 the creation of images using docker-compose was executed correctly and images are working as expected (without adding **stdin_open:true** and **tty:true** in docker-compose).

3) Also this issue using the images created on point 1 is solved.